# Selection sort in ascending order of array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection

I can get my program to sort in descending, but not ascending. I can't get my code to switch between them. Shouldn't I just be able to swicth the -- to ++? I need to use selection sort. In my bubble sort code, I could just change a few small things. Is that the case here? Or do I have to write an entire different section?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Gates_sortingSelection{

public static void main(String[] args){

  //ask user for the amount of values in the array      
  String amountS;
  amountS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many numbers would you like to sort?", 
        "Sorting Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  int amount = Integer.parseInt(amountS);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Please enter " + amount + " numbers you wish to sort.", 
        "Sorting Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  int[] numbers = new int [amount];

  //a loop that will ask for as many numbers the user specified
  for(int i = 1; i <= amount; i++){
     String tempS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number " + i + ": ");
     int temp = Integer.parseInt(tempS);
     numbers[i - 1] = temp; 
  }

  String which = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Would you like your values sorted in ascending (A), or descending (D) order?", 
        "Sorting Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

  if(!(which.equals("A") || which.equals("D"))){
     which = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please choose ascending (A) or descending (D).", 
        "Sorting Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  if(which.equals("D")){
     //initialize the descending method
     sortD(numbers);
  }

  if(which.equals("A")){
     //initialize the ascending method
     sortA(numbers);
  }

}

public static void sortD(int[] tosort){

  int[] original = tosort.clone();      //copy the original array to send into the next method

  int i, j, first, temp;
  for(i = tosort.length-1; i > 0; i--){

     first = 0;     //initializes to subscript of first element
     for(j=1; j<=i; j++){    //locates the smallest elememt between position 1 and i 
        if(tosort[j] < tosort[first])
        first = j;
     }

     temp = tosort[first];   //swaps the smallest number found with the element in position i

     tosort[first] = tosort[i];
     tosort[i] = temp;
  }

print(tosort, original);      //send both the original array and the sorted array to the next method to print

}
```

This is where the ascending code starts

```
public static void sortA(int[] tosort){

  int[] original = tosort.clone();      //copy the original array to send into the next method

  int i, j, first, temp;
  for(i = tosort.length-1; i > 0; i++){

     first = 0;     //initializes to subscript of first element
     for(j=1; j>=i; j++){    //locates the smallest elememt between position 1 and i 
        if(tosort[j] < tosort[first])
        first = j;
     }

     temp = tosort[first];   //swaps the smallest number found with the element in position i

     tosort[first] = tosort[i];
     tosort[i] = temp;
  }

print(tosort, original);      //send both the original array and the sorted array to the next method to print

}


public static void print(int[] sorted, int[] unsorted){

  //print the original array, and the sorted array
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Your original five numbers are: " 
           + Arrays.toString(unsorted) + ". \nYour new five numbers are: " 
           + Arrays.toString(sorted) + ".", "Sorted Arrays", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}


}
```

Comment: It'd probably be worth keeping track of whether the array has been previously sorted, and if so whether it is currently in descending order or ascending order.  If the array was just sorted descending and nothing has been added to it, if the user wants descending sort again, just return it as is without modification.  If the user wants ascending sort, just return it backwards rather than resorting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sortA method, the following line has errors

```
for(i = tosort.length-1; i > 0; i++){
```

You can't start at the last index and then increment your counter upward. Try this:

```
for(i = tosort.length-1; i > 0; i--){
```

Also, the inner lines in that for loop should be changed to

```
for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) { // locates the greatest elememt between
                                        // position 0 and i
                if (tosort[j] > tosort[first])
                    first = j;
            }
```

Since you want in ascending order, it should find the greatest number, not the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to sort, you could use Arrays.sort(anArray) instead of implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are other errors in your code, but I wouldn't attempt to reverse the whole sorting algorithm, just the comparison.  Instead of sorting the smallest number to the head of your array, aim for the largest.  So if sortAscending is a boolean that determines the sort direction, use the following code:

```
if((tosort[j] < tosort[first] && sortAscending) || (tosort[j] > tosort[first] && !sortAscending) {
    first = j;
}
```

Comment: What do I replace with this? The inner for loop? Or the if statement? I am confused since I don't understand why it is so different than the descending sorting method.

Comment: Yes, just the if statement.  And this will sort both ascending and descending depending on the boolean value (which you'd presumable pass into the method.  Or you can just replace the if statement with: if(tosort[j] > tosort[first]) first = j;